# How to keep a div visible on page re-size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a facebook "like us" icon on one site, now client requirement is to keep it visible when user scrolls the up until it reaches the top position of page (which is sorted by using jquery stickynotes) and the icon should still be visible when somebody re-size the browser (`X = (browser width/2) + (wrapper/2)`).

Not able to make out how can I do that, since first condition forces the div to be static positioned so that it can move-along when the page is scrolled down.

But in order to re-position it I'll require to make the potion fixed.

Kindly suggest a way out.

Comment: Could you share a demo - [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) - to make it easier to help you with the code.

Comment: Please have a look at http://tiny.cc/itl6gw "Sticky Widget" div works the same way as i need, just I need to re position it on browser re-size.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example how you can fix that:

```
function movement() {

    var topPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(topPosition > 100) {

        // do something
        $('element').addClass('dosomething');   

    } else {

        // do something
        $('element').removeClass('dosomething');    
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        movement();
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure if you have read the sample code i pasted, this portion is already done, I am working on re-size module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at something like [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)?

I'm not sure it's an exact match, but it solves some of these problems elegantly.

Comment: Scott : It works for sticky div but for preposition page is behaving correctly because of HTML5, I can't use HTML5.